# Kafka connect Graceful stop of task failed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Context: using kafka connect 7.4.0 to read data from Postgres views and write to another Postgres tables.

All works good, but whenever I stop the source connectors via the rest api, I always get:

```
Graceful stop of task (task-name-here) failed.
```

Funny enough, it's only the task itself that fails to shutdown gracefully. The connector itself does, as I have this log entry a few milliseconds earlier than the one above:

```
Graceful stop of connector (connector-name-here) succeeded.
```

Connectors are shutdown using:

```
DEL http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors/connector_name_here
```

The **sink** connectors and tasks shutdown just fine. It's just the **source** tasks that fails.

The timeout has been increased, but didn't help: `task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms=60000`

The connectors are definetely not running (ie, reading data from source database) cause the operation finished already for quite some time. The connectors are set to run once per day, to load data during the night.

`offset.flush.interval.ms=10000` in development and integration environments.
`offset.flush.interval.ms=60000` in production and uat.

It happens on all environments.

Any idea why the tasks fails to shutdown gracefully? This is logged as ERROR, and I need to get rid of these false positives in our alerting system.

Comment: What if you use the pause API instead of completely deleting the connector?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure this would do the trick, as I guess the pause would be affected by the same issue as the stop (now comes from the dedicated thread for the task (see my answer below). Will do a test and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting kafka users mailing list, the issue is likely caused to a change in Kafka Connect related to which thread the stop signals to the tasks is executed from. Kafka connect JDBC did not adapt to this change yet.

An [issue has been raised](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/1360) in the kafka-connect-jdbc repo.